# Enter non-game moves in ChessBase

Tags: chessbase, annotation

One problem I have with ChessBase is that often I need to enter moves that are non sequential in a comment. For example, I might have a comment like "with the idea of g5 followed by Bb7". There is no way to enter these moves, I just have to type them in as text. As an extreme example of non-sequential moves, there is of course the chess game from "Through the Looking Glass" which features many out of order (illegal) moves.

The bizarre thing is that ChessBase has a "with the idea of" Informant symbol (the delta), but this annotation is useless, because you always use it with a non-sequential move, which you cannot enter.

Is there any way around this dilemma? Note that I am using ChessBase 9.0, so more recent versions may have additional capability.

UPDATE -------------------------------

I tried entering a null move according to an answer below, and this is the result:

[image]

So, this kind of works and allows use of the annotation symbol, but it does look a little kooky with the dashes.

Comment: In Chessbase, ideas are usually expressed with graphical commenting (arrows, highlighted squares).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter a null move by ctrl+alt+0.

Comment: Thanks for the information about that feature of which I was unaware. I updated my question with the results. The blue text shows more like what I am aiming at.

Comment: This is entering a variation.  Just return to a move and enter another.  In your example, go to the position before c4 was played and enter Nf3.  By right clicking the move/variation, you can make it the main line, delete, and other functions.

Comment: You can also enter a text comment.  Ctrl+A inserts after the move, and Shift+Ctrl+A insert before the move.  It should also be found under the insert menu.